# Old Style Implementation of Tuple in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

Recently I was learning about TypeList and its algorithms in C++. When reading about its uses i got to know that TypeList along with the help of ClassHierarchy generators can be used to create Tuple Type in C++ (Andrei Alexandrescu). So i tried to write an implementation of it based on ClassHierarchy generator which is given below

**Hierarchy Generator :**

```
    // Class Hierarchy Generator :  This class acts as a code generator for many different uses ( like tuple )
    // Input  : TypeList, Holder(Holds a value of required Type)
    // Output : A type that has publicly inherited itself from Holders of all the types in TypeList

    template<class TypeList, template<class> class Holder>
    struct HierarchyGen;

    template<class AtomicType, template<class> class Holder>
    struct HierarchyGen : public Holder<AtomicType> {

        // Leftbase in all case represents the value Holder
        typedef Holder<AtomicType> LeftBase;
    };

    template<class Head,class Tail, template<class>class Holder>
    struct HierarchyGen < TypeList<Head, Tail>, Holder> : public HierarchyGen<Head, Holder>, public HierarchyGen<Tail, Holder> {

        typedef HierarchyGen<Head,Holder> LeftBase;
        typedef HierarchyGen<Tail,Holder> RightBase;
    };


    // If null type inherit nothing 
    template< template<class>class Holder>
    struct HierarchyGen< NullType, Holder> {};
```

**At :** Recurses through a Hierarchy and gets the type at given index

```
//At : This structure helps us in getting the type at given index
    // Input  : HierarchyGen , index
    // Output : The type at index
    // Algorithm:
    /*
       if index is 0 then
          Result = current_Hierarchygen::LeftBase
       else 
          Result = At<current_Hierarchygen::RightBase , index-1>

    */

    // Primary template
    template<class hierarchgen, unsigned int index>
    struct At;


    template<class hierarchgen, unsigned int index>
    struct At {


        typedef typename At<typename hierarchgen::RightBase, index - 1>::Result Result;

    };

    template<class hierarchgen>
    struct At<hierarchgen,0> {

        typedef  typename hierarchgen::LeftBase Result;
    };
```

**Get :** Used to fetch value from a tuple

```
// Functions cannot be partially specialized Hence the type2type and int2type trick is used
    template< class Hierarchy, class Result>
    inline Result& Get_Helper(Hierarchy& obj, type_to_type<Result>, int2type<0>){
        // Assign main object to the required type ( Perticular value instance ( Holder) will be then accessed )
        typename  Hierarchy::LeftBase& subobj= obj;
        return subobj;  
    }

    template<class Hierarchy,class Result, unsigned  index>
    inline Result& Get_Helper(Hierarchy& obj, type_to_type<Result> dummy, int2type<index>) {
        // Its traversing a hierarchy recursively
        typename  Hierarchy::RightBase& subobj = obj;
        return Get_Helper(subobj, dummy, int2type<index - 1>());
    }


    template<unsigned index, class Hierarchy>
    typename At<Hierarchy, index>::Result::holding_type& Get(Hierarchy& obj) {

        typedef typename At<Hierarchy, index>::Result Result;
        return Get_Helper(obj, type_to_type<Result>(), int2type<index>()).value;
    }
```

**Usage :**

```
template<class TypeList>
using tuple = HierarchyGen < TypeList,holder>;
//...
tuple<TYPELIST_3(int,int,int)> my_tuple;
    Get<0>(my_tuple) = 4;
    Get<1>(my_tuple) = 8;
    Get<2>(my_tuple) = 7;
    std::cout << " tuple<int,int,int> {4,8,7) :" << Get<0>(my_tuple)<<" "<< Get<1>(my_tuple)<<" "<< Get<2>(my_tuple);
    Get<0>(my_tuple) = 9;
    Get<1>(my_tuple) = 9;
    Get<2>(my_tuple) = 9;
    std::cout << "\nAfter Modifying :" << Get<0>(my_tuple) << " " << Get<1>(my_tuple) << " " << Get<2>(my_tuple);
```

I haven't looked at the implementations of tuple in Loki or Boost since i was just practising template metaprogramming. Is there something that I can improve? I am aware of the fact that variadic templates and parameter packs ease the task of creating a tuple type. Also in modern C++ do typelist have a use ?